# How do you deal with labels collisions?

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to export a "mini-map" (569*238) and I'm facing a collision issue with labels when I want to extent to the vector_source.I must display them, it means I can't play with overlapping, or resolution. I'm aware I can set a maximum width like shown in this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html) but in my case it's not relevant as I'm working with city names.

I tried to create a [snippet](http://codepen.io/poupi/pen/OXPKyE) to show you how that works but  it seems the projection is not good (all is set at [0,0]).

```
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: (new             ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)  
      });

function styleFunction (feature) {
       return new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 1
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
          }),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
             text: feature.get('PORT_NAME'),
             fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({


  color: '#FFFF99',
            width: 3.5
          })
        })
      });
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction
      });


var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }), vectorLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [45, 0],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

I guess my need is to shift my labels and link them to their points with a line, but I can't figure out how to make it work, or if such a solution already exist.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: for your codepen to work just add the 4326 projection to your view --> `view: new ol.View({
          center: [45, 0],
          projection:'EPSG:4326',
          zoom: 4
        })` for your case check the cluster example -->http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Snippet is alright now. I can't use clusters as labels need to be visible (this is supposed to be a "circuit" (not sure it's saying like that in english)